# How to upgrade Magento 2 eway extension via composer?

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I want to install eway magento 2 extension in my magento 2 website but during installation it asking me to upgrade composer. can someone please let me know how to upgrade composer?
I want to install eway rapid extension in magento 2.3 which is free enxtension in magento marketplace.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Magento 2.3 directory, run the command (note, please ensure you are using the latest version)

```
composer require eway/eway-rapid-magento2 3.0.1
```

Then ensure everything is updated with

```
composer update
```

Enable the module with the following command:

```
bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Eway_DirectConnection Eway_SharedPage Eway_SecureFields Eway_IFrame Eway_TransparentRedirect Eway_EwayRapid
```

Install the module by running

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Run the compile command to finish:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate "please ensure you are using the latest version"?
What If I am not using latest?

Comment: module latest version

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: Also I am getting following error when I ran that above mentioned command
http://prntscr.com/n29i67
http://prntscr.com/n29ijo

Comment: upgrade php version because magento 2.3 not support php version 5.6

Comment: required php version is 5.6.5 ,7.0.2, 7.0.4, 7.0.6

Answer (score 0):

The instructions can vary depending on your operating system, but the [Composer help page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-) for upgrading provides the following:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Could not open input file: composer.phar".

Comment: @MithiTechie the command will depend on how and where composer is installed. Maybe try `composer self-update`

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem Marketplace download Installation not working.

Follow Composer Installation:

1. In the Magento 2 directory, run the command (note, please ensure you are using the latest version)

> composer require eway/eway-rapid-magento2 3.0.2

2. Then ensure everything is updated with

> composer update

3. Enable the module with the following command:

> bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Eway_DirectConnection
>   Eway_SharedPage Eway_SecureFields Eway_IFrame Eway_TransparentRedirect
>   Eway_EwayRapid

4. Install the module by running

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

5. Run the compile command to finish:

> bin/magento setup:di:compile

[main link](https://go.eway.io/s/article/How-do-I-install-the-eWAY-Magento-2-extension)

Hope someone may be get help